# Bash: Sum values in one column based on key

Tags: bash, awk

I have log file with following structure:

```
DATE:AMZN:209:159.99
DATE:AMZN:300:159.99
DATE:GOOGL:75:552.03
DATE:GOOGL:300:1091.50
DATE:GOOGL:100:199.99
DATE:TSLA:19:9019.99
```

What I want to do is to count total quantity(3. column) for every company(2. column) that can be found in log file. So, the result in this case should be:

```
AMZN:509
GOOGL:475
TSLA:19
```

I tried using `awk` and `sort`, though I don't have much experience with those utilities. If you have any advise, please post it down bellow.

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried something like this: `awk -F ':' '$2 ~ $2 {sum=sum+$3}{print sum}'`. 
It looks like this statement is printing sum for every line in log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {a[$2]+=$3} END{for(i in a){print i OFS a[i]}}' file | sort
```

With GNU `awk` and without `sort`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{a[$2]+=$3}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_desc"; for(i in a)print i FS a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
AMZN:509
GOOGL:475
TSLA:19
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)